# In Android, what's the best way to communicate between a service and a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I need to be able to have a service "tell" a BroadcastReceiver to do some work, and then wait until that work is done, and once it's finished, the BroadcastReceiver needs to send the result back to the service. And at that point, the service can continue execution.

So, "sending" the work from the service to the BroadcastReceiver is easy -- I just send a broadcast with the intent using extras for the work that needs to be done. But I don't know how to have the BroadcastReceiver then send the results back to the service. What's the best way to do this?

**Edit:**
I should have mentioned that the service in question is actually a contact sync adapter service. I'm not sure if that makes a difference, but maybe it does. Some of the work can't be done in the scope of the sync adapter, and that's why I'm offloading it to be done by the broadcastreceiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a Second inline Broadcast Receiver from the Service just to receive the results from the First Broadcast receiver. Pass the data via Intent. In the Second Broadcast receivers **onReceive()** do whatever you want.

Unregister the Second Broadcast Receiver in **onDestroy** of the Service.

Comment: What would that accomplish? I still need to get the resulting data back into the service, so how would a second broadcast receiver help?

Comment: What I am suggesting is inline broadcast receiver within service. This will have access to all service properties and methods..

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I missed that. And in that case, couldn't I just send the intents directly to the service and process them in onStartCommand?